# How to find sequence of characters matching an identifier in Linux/Unix?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, grep

I have a fasta file called `mytext.fasta`.

mytext.fasta

```
>lcl|NW_001820834.1_gene_4 [locus_tag=SS1G_01081] [db_xref=GeneID:5493597] [partial=5',3'] [location=complement(<6452..>8801)] [gbkey=Gene]
ATGCAATTGGCAGCAGTCCTAAGCCTCGTGGGCTTGGTTACGGCTCAATGTCCGTACGGATTTGACACAC
CACTTCAAAAGCGTGAATCTATTGATGCTCAAGCCAGTAGTTCTAGTTTCTTGAATCAATTCACAATTAA
CGATACCGATGCACACTTTACCACCGACGCAGGTGGGCCTATGCAAGAGGACACTAGTTTGAAAGCTGGG
>lcl|NW_001820834.1_gene_5 [locus_tag=SS1G_01082] [db_xref=GeneID:5493601] [partial=5',3'] [location=<9695..>10785] [gbkey=Gene]
ATGTTTTCCGGTCCCCAGAAACTTGGCAACGCCAAACAAAAATCAATTGGCCTCGCTTGTCACACAATTA
GTCCCCACGAAGCCTTGTACAAACTAGCCACTGGCTCGTCCCGGACCATTAGGGCAATGTTCAACAGAGA
>lcl|NW_001820834.1_gene_6 [locus_tag=SS1G_01083] [db_xref=GeneID:5494096] [partial=5',3'] [location=<12203..>15199] [gbkey=Gene]
ATGAGAGGCAAGCTTGGTGTCACAGTTGCTGCATTTGCGACGGCATTTCTAAATACGACACTTGCTCAAG
ACTCAACATCATCACAAGCGGATGCGGATACTACCACAAGTTATTGTCCCGTTTACACGCTCACAGCTTC
AGTTGATGCCAGCGCACCTATTATCCCAAACATCCACGATCCGCAGGCAATTAATCCACAAGATGTTTGT
CCGGGGTATACTGCATCCAATGTGAAGCGAACCTCTCACGGATTGACGGCTTCTCTGTCATTGGCTGGTG
```

When I do `grep -A1 'SS1G_01082' mytext.fasta`, I get:

```
>lcl|NW_001820834.1_gene_5 [locus_tag=SS1G_01082] [db_xref=GeneID:5493601] [partial=5',3'] [location=<9695..>10785] [gbkey=Gene]
ATGTTTTCCGGTCCCCAGAAACTTGGCAACGCCAAACAAAAATCAATTGGCCTCGCTTGTCACACAATTA
```

Instead I want to get:

```
>lcl|NW_001820834.1_gene_5 [locus_tag=SS1G_01082] [db_xref=GeneID:5493601] [partial=5',3'] [location=<9695..>10785] [gbkey=Gene]
ATGTTTTCCGGTCCCCAGAAACTTGGCAACGCCAAACAAAAATCAATTGGCCTCGCTTGTCACACAATTA
GTCCCCACGAAGCCTTGTACAAACTAGCCACTGGCTCGTCCCGGACCATTAGGGCAATGTTCAACAGAGA
```

If you notice, every sequence starts with `>` in this file, so I want to get the full length of sequence when I do grep. How can I get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier with `gnu awk` using a custom `RS`:

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)>' '/SS1G_01082/{print RT $0}' file
```

```
>lcl|NW_001820834.1_gene_5 [locus_tag=SS1G_01082] [db_xref=GeneID:5493601] [partial=5',3'] [location=<9695..>10785] [gbkey=Gene]
ATGTTTTCCGGTCCCCAGAAACTTGGCAACGCCAAACAAAAATCAATTGGCCTCGCTTGTCACACAATTA
GTCCCCACGAAGCCTTGTACAAACTAGCCACTGGCTCGTCCCGGACCATTAGGGCAATGTTCAACAGAGA
```

Comment: @anbhava Thanks, but not sure why this doesn't work when I do piping.

Comment: My command looks like this: `esearch -db nuccore -q 'SS1G_01082[gene]' | efilter -source refseq -molecule genomic | efetch -format gene_fasta | awk -v RS= '/SS1G_01082/'`. The last bit (`awk -v RS= '/SS1G_01082/'`) is supposed to filter out the desired sequence, but it is giving me everything.

Comment: if `esearch -db nuccore -q 'SS1G_01082[gene]' | efilter -source refseq -molecule genomic | efetch -format gene_fasta` command gives output exact same as shown above i.e. a blank line after each record then this `awk` should work

Comment: No, the output doesn't have blank lines. I have updated my question.